# Forge Viewer - Failed to parse OTG

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am using the Forge Viewer APIs to visualize OTG models (from our BIM360 account) into our web application. All used to work fine in the last few months but since this morning i started to receive some browser errors related to the OTG geometry

- Invalid OTG heders
- Failed to parce OTG geometry
- Failed to parse geometry ﵌䐮砦溔헜縗ﭤ촧퐤
- Error loading mesh ﵌䐮砦溔헜縗ﭤ촧퐤
  (some logs are displayed in chinese languange and all of them are repeated multiple times into the browser console)

the result reflect an incorrect loaded geometry.
I'm using the latest Viewer Version --> LMV_VIEWER_VERSION "7.33.1"

I logged into my BIM360 account today and got new messages related to platform updates.
https://blogs.autodesk.com/bim360-release-notes/2020/12/08/bim-360-document-management-updates-dec-8-2020/

This is not the first time that the BIM360 platform updates without any comunication. Are those errors related to some kind of BIM360 platform update?

The model I am loading refers to a ".rvt" file, the last version uploaded to BIM360 some 7 days ago. I can visualize the same model from BIM360 website correctly and without any errors

Comment: NOTE - The last ".rvt" version was uploaded 7 days ago to BIM360 (latest version is now V6). We are still using V5 in our web Application. Does OTG extension requies always the latest version to be displayed into the viewer?

Comment: UPDATE - I tryied to load the latest Version (V6), all works fine without any errors. V5 is still not working

Comment: It is indeed a strange issue.
To answer your question, as long a version has a OTG manifest, you should be able to load the model in the latest version of the viewer.
Without having a sample to reproduce the issue, it is hard to guess what is wrong. Do you think you could share V5 and V6 with us for testing?