# Autodesk Forge Viewer - Invalid OGT header with SVF2 format

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-bim360

When I migrate my Forge Viewer from SVF to SVF2, some of the geometry is not loaded and I get "Invalid OGT header" and "Failed to parse OGT geometry" for each element.

[Console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rT4p4.png)

I'm obtaining the models directly from BIM360.
I'm using Nodejs with express and doing a post request to communicate Forge access token with the client

```
app.get('/home', (req, res) => {

var options = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'url': 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate',
    'headers': {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Cookie': 'PF=boZ6jpDwlNEmVzAGFiFx8i'},
form: {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'client_id': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'client_secret': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'scope': 'data:read data:write'}};
```

I just replaced the SVF viewer options with the ones in the [Autodesk Post](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/svf2-public-beta-new-optimized-viewer-format)

```
function launchViewer(urn) {

//SVF
//var options = {
//env: 'AutodeskProduction',
//getAccessToken: getToken,
//api: 'derivativeV2' + (atob(urn.replace('_', '/')).indexOf('emea') > -1 ? '_EU' : '')};

//SVF2
var options = {
env: 'MD20ProdUS',
getAccessToken: getToken,
api: 'D3S'};


Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, () => {

viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D(document.getElementById('forgeViewer'));
viewer.start();

var documentId = 'urn:' + urn;
Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);});

function onDocumentLoadSuccess(doc) {
var viewables = doc.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, viewables).then((i) => {
  // documented loaded, any action?
});

this.viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, onSelectionChanged);
this.viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT, onGeometryLoaded);  
}

function onGeometryLoaded(){ 
 console.log(viewer);
}

function onDocumentLoadFailure(viewerErrorCode) {
 console.error('onDocumentLoadFailure() - errorCode:' + viewerErrorCode);
}}
```

Finally obtain the token from the server

```
//Localhost
function getToken(_callback) {
    $.get("http://localhost:3000/home", function(data, status){
    var response = JSON.parse(data);
    _callback(response.access_token, response.expires_in);
 });
}
```

Any clue what might be happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using SVF2 since 2 months and are now experiencing this problem for one of our models which worked without a problem before. However, most models work fine. It seems SVF2 regressed.

However, we use the EMEA environment:

```js
{
     'env': 'MD20ProdEU', //svf2
     'api': 'D3S', //svf2
     ...
}
```

[image: Chrome dev tools error message]

#### Edit:

I researched a little bit more. Our local development instance hosted on port 1841 has the error only for one model. Our properly hosted viewer instance on port 80 has no error for the same model. (Tested for viewer version 7.34 and 7.33)

#### Edit 2:

Related Stackeoverflow question without an answer unfortunetely: [Forge Viewer - Failed to parse OTG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65215354/forge-viewer-failed-to-parse-otg)

#### Edit 3:

Some of our users experience the OGT error for some models while other users don't have any problems with the same setup.

Comment: There is some weird behavior here, I tried the exact same configuration and I only get the issue using the Revit Sample model and not with the rest of them. Good thins is I tried the EMEA environment and now all the models work, I don't know what might be the difference but that did it.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was introduced with the transition to SVF2 and it keeps coming back, even 2 years later.

To temporarily fix this you need to clear the browsers IndexedDB, eg. in Chrome open dev tools -> Application -> expand IndexedDB -> delete the `otg` database. After this loading models will work for a while until the viewer corrupts the local db again. This is very frustrating.